# Why doesn't spacy given any children to the root node?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Here's my code:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))
doc = nlp("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(list(sent.root.children))
```

I'm expecting `sent.root.children` to contain links to other words / sentence fragments like maybe `lazy` or `brown`, but it's an empty array. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is quite simple: getting the root of the sentence and its children requires the dependency parse. This means that you need to have a model loaded that includes weights to predict the dependencies.

In your code, you're only importing the `English` language class, which only includes language-specific rules and tokenizer. You can download the default small English model like this (or any of the [other options](https://spacy.io/models/en)):

```
python -m spacy download en
```

You can then use `spacy.load()` to load in the model. Under the hood, this tells spaCy to find the model installed as `'en'`, check its meta data to initialise the respective language class (`English`), construct the processing pipeline (parser, tagger, NER), and make the weights available to enable spaCy to make predictions. Since the default sentence boundary detector uses the dependency parse, it will be included already – so there's no need to add it to the pipeline manually.

Just tested your example, and it now prints a list of the root's children:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(list(sent.root.children))
# [fox, over, .]
```